# Basis for set of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

I just did a problem where I think I am able to draw the following conlusion

> The set of all polynomials with *complex* coeff of degree $\le n$
>
> has the same basis as
>
> The set of all polynomials with *real* coeff degree $\le n$,
>
> namely {$ 1,x,x^2,...,x^n$}.

is the statement correct?

Comment: The complex polynomials have the same dimension over $\mathbb{C}$ as the real polynomials have over $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basis of all polynomials of degree $\le n$ is ${1,x,x^2,...,x^n}$ no matter of the field of the scalars. It's so because the 'coordinates' of the 'vectors' (read polynomials) are a linear combination of the set ${1,x,x^2,...,x^n}$ where the scalars before any element of that set are from a given field (real, complex or any other).

Comment: Minor complaint: That should read "*One* basis of all polynomials...". After all, there certainly are other bases...